# Removing =hyperlink from excel rows

Tags: excel

Hi I a lot of columns/rows in my excel worksheet that has:

=HYPERLINK(link,text)

I want to remove everything and just leave the link/url part as I'm importing this excel file into mysql. I know I can just do a replace or parse the field programatically but I was thinking if I can just remove it from excel it would be quicker to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: there is nothing quicker than replacing the `*(` and `,*` parts

Comment: Problem is I saved the file into CSV and since =hyperlink is treated as a formula, the text was retained removing the links

Answer (score 0):

I think pasting values would be appropriate here. If you're using Windows, you can copy all of the cells in your worksheet, press ctrl + alt + v to open the "Paste Special" window, and select values to simply paste the text.